# Jenkins not connecting on AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

I have launched an ubuntu EC2 instance and tried to install Jenkins on it.

Below are the commands i used

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/"
sudo apt install jenkins
```

My jenkins installation was successful but when i go to browser and tried
http://172.31.38.179:8080/.I am not able to get the jenkins page

Please suggest what i am missing here ?

Comment: Did you check whether you have open tcp port 8080 in your security group in ec2 ?

Comment: Actually when we launch a new instance we need to make sure that default Jenkins port should be open in the launch configuration security group go and add TCP  port 8080 from all and you are good to go . Please let me know if it works or not

Comment: Great....Thanks Prabhat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the security group attached to your ec2 instance.
Edit and add TCP on port 8080 from all and you are good to go . Please let me know if there’s any issues.

Comment: It is not working...i have properly attached the security group but Jenkins is not accessible.....